# Object oriented programming vs. the split function... which is better?

Tags: java, oop

here is the non-oop way of doing it:

When someone presses a day on a calendar, we need to find out the day, and path. Here is the non-oop way of storing that information:
A string was created with a "-" delimiter between each piece of info we need, like this:

```
 12-c:\files\john_doe.png
```

Then it was stored in an array. However, to retrieve the data, we then use the "split" function like this.

```
for (int t = 0;t < day_and_path.length;t++)
```

{

```
String[] day_from_db = day_and_path[t].split("-");
String day_db = day_from_db[0];
String path_db = day_from_db[1];
```

However the OOP way is, make a class with properties: day, path. Then store them into an array of objects.

Which way is better and why?

Comment: I'm not sure its a fair fight between all of object orientated and just one function

Comment: Also; OOP is much better than that for internal data. Holding all your internal data as a single string is .....lacking in sanity

Comment: What do you mean with 'better'? Easier to read? Prettier to print? Faster to compile? More intensely using String-functions?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `String#split`, you'll be dealing with an array of strings. If all you do is assign the strings to local variables, then there is no point in making a class for that.

If you want to hold on to the string parts and pass them around to other methods, then it begins to make sense to have an object which will conveniently encapsulate those strings.

Comment: +1 - OOP should be viewed as a tool ... not a religion.